# Filtrar valores booleanos

Tags: javascript, react, filter, map

Estou tentando filtrar valores de um array onde tenho um obj de índice `0` que possui a chave `cimentado`, de valor `true` e um outro obj `1` com a chave `cimentado` de valor `false`.
Porém, haverá casos onde certos objetos possuirão `cimentado` e `parafusado`, pois dessa forma o mesmo objeto é exibido em ambos os casos. Alguma abordagem boa pra isso?

Consegui uma abordagem aqui, mas não sei se seria a ideal. Repliquei um objeto que era cimentado `true` com cimentado `false`, no caso o mesmo produto com chave de valor diferente, dessa forma ele mostra tanto se for `true` como `false`.

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "nome": "Munhão Provisório",
    "imagem": "munhao-provisorio-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  },
{
    "id": "2",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": false,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  }
]
```

Nessa checagem abaixo estou fazendo um map onde é retornado o valor que dá match o que vem do JSON e o valor do estado atual. Se for `true`, retorna somente os objetos com chave de valor `true`. Isso funciona perfeitamente, já que um é `true` e outro é `false`. Contudo, em outros casos podem existir objetos que devem aparecer em ambos os estados. Não sei se a abordagem com valores booleanos de fato seria a melhor forma para isso.

```
{itemLevel2.cimentado === cimentado && (
  // código
)}
```

Essas foram minhas tentativas, mas obviamente falta coisa.

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aumentei o tamanho do array para permitir mais testes.

Função para filtrar o array desejado:

```
// Função para filtrar o array que recebe o array a ser filtrado e o objeto do filtro.
let array_filtrado = function filtrarArray(ar_dados, obj_filtro){
  return ar_dados.filter(function(item){
    for(obj in obj_filtro){
      if(obj_filtro[obj] !== item[obj]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  },obj_filtro);
}
```

Veja abaixo o código completo e funcionando.

```js
// Array de dados para testes
let dados = [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "nome": "Munhão Provisório",
    "imagem": "munhao-provisorio-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  },
{
    "id": "2",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "cimentado": false,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": false,
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  }
  ,
  {
    "id": "4",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": false,
    "cimentado": false,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  }
   ,
  {
    "id": "5",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": false,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  } ,
  {
    "id": "6",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "torque": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  } ,
  {
    "id": "7",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "cimentado": false,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  } ,
  {
    "id": "8",
    "nome": "Ucla Plástica base CrCo",
    "imagem": "ucla-plastica-base-crco-a31",
    "cimentado": true,
    "tipoConexao": "rotacionalAntiRotacional",
    "familia": "A3.1"
  }
];

// Função para filtrar o array que recebe o array a ser filtrado e o objeto do filtro.
let array_filtrado = function filtrarArray(ar_dados, obj_filtro){
  return ar_dados.filter(function(item){
    for(obj in obj_filtro){
      if(obj_filtro[obj] !== item[obj]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  },obj_filtro);
}


// Retornos da função
console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:true, cimentado:true})); // Retorna objetos ID 0 e 1

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:true, cimentado:false})); // Retorna objetos ID 2

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:false, cimentado:false})); // Retorna objetos ID 4

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:false, cimentado:true})); // Retorna objetos ID 3

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:undefined, cimentado:false})); // Retorna objetos ID 7

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:undefined, cimentado:true})); // Retorna objetos ID 8

console.log(array_filtrado(dados, {torque:true, cimentado:undefined})); // Retorna objetos ID 6
```

Comment: Isso me deu um novo ponto de vista! No entanto, vou esse seria a princípio 1 filtro da tabela atual. Eu tenho 1 array para uma lista de items que possuem  valores como: `favorável` ou `desfavorável` | `múltiplo` ou `unitário`. Na tela anterior eu salvo em um form e retorno esse array trazendo o valor booleano desses itens e comparo na tela atual, filtrando separadamente. Então no caso, existe um filtro que é aplicado na tabela atual e um outro que vem do salvamento do form anterior. A parte do `Cimentado` | `Parafusado` está ok, agora essa outra que vem do form é a que está mais complicada

Comment: Não entendi direito, sobre a sua pergunta original... a minha resposta atendeu? Se atendeu poderia marcar a minha resposta como aceita para para a sua pergunta! Qual a parte que vem do form? Pode gerar outra pergunta para ela e postar o link aqui nos comentários que te ajudo com ela.

Comment: Form p/ alguns itens podem aceitar valores: 
**Unitário** || **Múltipla** || **Ambas** && **Favorável** => retorna o que se enquadrar nesse critério.

OU

**Unitário** || **Múltipla** || **Ambas** && **Favorável** || **Desfavorável** || **Ambas**

Já na tabela existe o filtro "pai" que define entre: 
**Cimentado** || **Parafusado** || **Ambos**

Essa tabela é a responsável por retornar esses itens que foram filtrados pelo form anterior, saca?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/554503/compara%c3%a7%c3%b5es-boolean-de-valores-entre-2-arrays-distintos